# Javascript method won't be executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a method in JavaScript which won't be executed..
Already debugged via Firebug, but I got no clue what the problem might be..

I have a table which cells should be filled with video links.
The variable `videoPath` contains the link. `vids.video` is my object.

```
var vids = {"video":
    [
        {
            "name": "Video 1",
            "path": "videos/band/vid1.f4v"
        },
        {
            "name": "Video 2",
            "path": "videos/band/vid2.f4v"
        }
    ]
};

var i = 0;
for (property in vids.video) {
    if(vids.video.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        videoPath = vids.video[i].path;
        $('table.videos tr').append("<td><a class='videolink' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='PlayVideo("+videoPath+")'>some divs</a></td>");
    }
    i++;
}


function PlayVideo(vidd) {
    alert(vidd); 
}
```

When I remove `vidd` from the methods brackets, it works fine:

```
$('table.videos tr').append("<td><a class='videolink' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='PlayVideo()'>some divs</a></td>");

function PlayVideo() {
    alert("It works!"); 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see where `videoPath` is being created. Is it a value in vids.video? If it is you want to use it like: `vids.video.videoPath`. You also need to var `property` in that loop.

Comment: From where you are getting videoPath ?

Comment: Does the `videoPath` string contain a string literal (with quotes) or only a variable name (without quotes)? Inspect the generated HTML and check whether you are getting a ReferenceError

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. You are confusing JavaScript object literals (a construct of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly. See also:  [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: I've added my JSON object

Comment: _Javascript_ object! :)

Comment: @P4tR: Check the link in my previous comment. It's not a JSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add single quotes around the argument to your `PlayVideo` call.

```
$('table.videos tr').append("<td><a class='videolink' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='PlayVideo(\\'"+videoPath+"\\')'>some divs</a></td>");
```

note the double backslash which will be necessary as you are specifying a literal string in javascript that should contain a backslash. the latter is needed as the result on the representation level of html contains a single quote in a literal with single quote delimiters.

of course you may enclose the `videoPath` argument with double quotes - here you have one level less of chracter escaping as you only have to escape the double quote in the argument to the `append` call while its not necessary to escape the double quote in the literal On the html level.

```
$('table.videos tr').append("<td><a class='videolink' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='PlayVideo(\""+videoPath+"\")'>some divs</a></td>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, the parameter for `PlayVideo` must be in `''`

```
var videoPath ="C:\\test.avi";

$('body').append("<a class='videolink' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"PlayVideo('" + videoPath + "')\">some divs</a>");
```

[jsFiddle - DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sSDVT/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some alternative code which removes the need for that lengthy append line, and removing the need for you to worry about what quote goes where.

```
var cell = '<td><a class="videolink" data-path="#{path}">#{name}</a></td>';

$('table.videos tr').each(function (index, element) {
  var path = vids.video[index].path;
  var name = vids.video[index].name;
  data = cell.replace('#{path}', path).replace('#{name}', name);
  $(this).append(data);
});

$(document).on('click', '.videolink', function () {
  playVideo($(this).data('path'));
});

function playVideo(path) {
  console.log(path);
}
```